# How to plot Capital Market Line

Tags: pgfplots

I don not how to plot the data in latex as the attach picture. It has consumed me so many days to try to figure out. I still don not solve this question. [image]

Comment: How would anyone possibly plot the data without knowing it? Please consider posting an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) showing what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Tex.SE!  Questions here are usually based around specific issues, and especially for graphics people will generally give more help if you show what you have tried and where you have got stuck.  http://texample.net is often a good place to start.

But since the diagram you posted is quite interesting and its a first post, here is an effort at it in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) that you might like to adapt.  There are plenty of tutorials and explanations if you follow the link.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    % axes
    path xx, yy;
    xx = origin -- 240 right;
    yy = xx rotated 90;

    % define some points
    z.T = (104, 144);
    z.P = (160, 189);
    z.R = whatever[z.T, z.P]; x.R = 0;
    z1  = whatever[z.T, z.P]; x1 = 200;
    z0 = (190, 10);

    % define a parabola-like curve through the points...
    path ff;
    ff = z0 .. controls (z.R shifted 10 up) 
                    and (z.R shifted 10 right) .. z.T --- z.P .. z1;

    % draw some lines
    draw ff withcolor 2/3 blue;
    draw z.R -- z.T dashed evenly;
    draw z.T -- z1 dashed evenly withcolor 2/3 red;
    draw (0, y.T) -- z.T -- (x.T,0) dashed withdots scaled 1/2;
    draw xx;
    draw yy;

    % add some labels...
    label.top("$\mu$", point 1 of yy);
    label.rt("$\sigma$", point 1 of xx);
    label.lft("$\mu_M$", (0, y.T));
    label.bot("$\sigma_M$", (x.T, 0));
    label.lft("$r_F$", z.R);

    dotlabel.lrt("$T$", z.T);
    dotlabel.lrt("$P$", z.P);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

You need to compile this with `lualatex`.  I've left the label and the arrow for you.